# Missing Server Side dependencies

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I am getting an alert in Sharepoint Central Admin that The SharePoint Health Analyzer has detected some critical issues.

On checking, I found the alerts like:

> [MissingSetupFile] File [Features\xxxx\xxxx\xxx] is referenced 1 times
>   in the database [PROD01_Content_xxxx], but exists only under Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation 2010 setup folder. Consider upgrading the
>   feature/solution which contains this file to the latest version. One
>   or more setup files are referenced in the database
>   [PROD01_Content_xxxx], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.
>
> [MissingFeature] Database [PROD01_Content_xxxx] has reference(s) to a
>   missing feature: Id = [f99f774c-6160-4bb6-8519-10e30b02d5b3]. The
>   feature with Id f99f774c-6160-4bb6-8519-10e30b02d5b3 is referenced in
>   the database [PROD01_Content_xxxx], but is not installed on the
>   current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please
>   install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if
>   necessary.
>
> [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [a9bc1035-cf56-e003-8a4d-fff0bb3da148]
>   (class
>   [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchApplicationSystemStatus]
>   from assembly [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]) is referenced 1
>   times in the database [PROD01_SharePoint_AdminContent], but is not
>   installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution
>   which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in
>   the database [PROD01_SharePoint_AdminContent], but are not installed
>   on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which
>   contains these web parts.

I followed the link:

http://get-spscripts.com/2011/06/removing-features-from-content-database.html

But unfortunately, on running the script, it shows the feature does not found.

One thing I would like to mention is: I've deployed the **sharepoint 2010 wsp on 2013 version**.Is this the reason for getting [MissingSetupFile] error?

What can I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you working on upgrading a site from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Not actually, but my site is developed in 2010 and deployment platform is 2013.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in full detail. Looks like some wsps are not deployed or some of the features inside them are not activated.

Comment: All the wsp are deployed, the functionality works well! Still I'm getting error message in Health Analyzer.